# How to toggle ingore whitespace in the magit revision buffer?

Tags: magit

In the *magit-log* buffer when return key is pressed it brings up the *magit-revison* buffer displaying the diff b/w previous commit and the current commit. Is there a way to toggle the ignore-whitespace in this buffer?

Answer (score 1):

In that revision buffer if you press `d-wd` ("diff", then select the "--ignore-all-space" option, then "dwim") it will open another buffer showing the commit diff without the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In the revision buffer, press `D-wg`.